# ¿Cómo añadir una columna a un dataframe en r que tome un determinado valor si otra columna tiene un valor específico?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe (a17) con una columna llamada row, la cual sus valores son las letras de la A a la H. Quiero añadir una columna llamada medio, en la que tome el valor medio1 si la columna llamada row tiene el valor A,B,C o D y medio2 si tiene el valor E,F,G o H.

Cuando lo pongo con un solo valor como aparece en el código siguiente funciona bien

```
a17[a17$row == "A", "Media Definition"] = "medio1"
a17[a17$row == "E", "Media Definition"] = "medio2"
```

Pero si lo pongo de esta forma no me funciona bien

```
a17[a17$row == c("A","B","C","D"), "Media Definition"] = "medio1"
a17[a17$row == c("E","F","G","H"), "Media Definition"] = "medio2"
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo para no tener que ir letra por letra?

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es comparar mediante  `a17$row %in% c("A","B","C","D")`

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la función case_when aninada a la función mutate del paquete de dplyr. Ejemplo:

`library(dplyr)`

```
#Creando datos Es bueno que coloques la estructura de datos a utilizar
rowe <- LETTERS |> head(8)


a17 <- data.frame(
  row = rep(rowe, 10),
  value = seq(1:80)
)


a17 |> 
  mutate(
    medio = case_when(
      row == c("A", "B", "C", "D") ~ "medio1",
      row == c("E", "F", "G", "H") ~ "medio2"
    )
  )
```

output:

```
   row value  medio
1    A     1 medio1
2    B     2 medio1
3    C     3 medio1
4    D     4 medio1
5    E     5 medio2
6    F     6 medio2
7    G     7 medio2
8    H     8 medio2
9    A     9 medio1
10   B    10 medio1
11   C    11 medio1
12   D    12 medio1
13   E    13 medio2
14   F    14 medio2
15   G    15 medio2
16   H    16 medio2
17   A    17 medio1
18   B    18 medio1
19   C    19 medio1
20   D    20 medio1
21   E    21 medio2
22   F    22 medio2
23   G    23 medio2
24   H    24 medio2
25   A    25 medio1
26   B    26 medio1
27   C    27 medio1
28   D    28 medio1
29   E    29 medio2
```